# Extract important values from a RDA MVA.plot

Tags: r

Here you have the data: samples in lines, metabolic compounds in columns:
[Tableau.txt](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4RrA_2io7N2RUludkFLVU9iNTA).

I run the RDA :

```
library(vegan)
library(RVAideMemoire)
Tableau = read.table("Tableau.txt", h=T)
Interaction = Tableau$Genotype : Tableau$ETM
RDA = rda(Tableau[,-c(1:4)] ~ Genotype*ETM, data=Tableau)
```

Then I draw the correlation circle:

```
MVA.plot(RDA, "correlations", space=1, points=FALSE, thresh = 0.8, cex=0.6)
```

[Correlation circle](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4RrA_2io7N2Q2hqTDA0dUEwVHc)

I would like to extract the names of the compounds that are displayed on the graph (M1, M2, M30...) because some are unreadable, and I would like to do it for other thresholds).

Do you have an idea about that?

Comment: I can't reproduce your example. Probably different `rda` version (`rda_1.0.2-2`).

Comment: I'm sorry, I wrote library(rda) but it was library(vegan), and you need also library(RVAideMemoire). I edited the question.